# Ubuntu Firefox - unsecure https connection - permanent exception is volatile

Tags: networking, firefox

Didn't find existing question this kind. However Ubuntu Firefox only is affected.

Problem was not observed with Firefox on other systems.
The router in local network offers its GUI via web interface with access under router's IP. I connect to its GUI using https.
Ubuntu Firefox claims every time the connection was not secure SEC_ERROR_UNKNOW_ISSUER. This is not yet the problem I like to discuss here.

The problem is myself lets Firefox to apply exception to that URL and store this exception permanently. In end-effect exception is not permanent but volatile - I have to do it every time when connecting to router GUI  There are some cases where it is not reproducible, however hard to describe conditions that exceptional observation was made under.

Is this a well-known problem?
Solutions known?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What happens when you disregard the error?

Comment: Could you please create a new (temporary) Firefox profile (run `firefox -no-remote -P` and use the appearing profile manager) and try to reproduce the issue with it? Thanks.

Comment: New profile created. Unfortunately no improvement. Described problem still reproducible.

Comment: Problem still not solved. Current status as my latest updates here.